# Erlang: how to disable "crash dump" & "core dump" generation?

Tags: erlang

Is there any way to disable the generation of "crash dump" & "core dump" files when running 'erl' ?

PS: I know about the "+d" option of erl but I want to completely disable the generation of crash/core dumps.

Comment: May I ask why? What's the big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are into dirty patching, you can insert a return statement right at the top of the erl_crash_dump_v function in break.c, and recompile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would rather have this work out of the box: I don't want to have to maintain another distro.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you either do this, or write a nice wish letter to the erlang development mailing list :)
Anyway, I would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You may also set the ERL_CRASH_DUMP environment variable to "/dev/null". It designates to which file the crash dump should be written.

See: https://github.com/yrashk/erlang/blob/e1282325ed75e52a98d58f5bd9fb0fa27896173f/erts/emulator/beam/break.c#L684

Comment: The above answer worked for me, can you suggest how to disable MnesiaCore file as well?