# Erlang: Disable MnesiaCore upon Mnesia Errors

Tags: debugging, erlang, mnesia

I have an application using Mnesia Database running is a memory constrained environment. So is there any way to disable MnesiaCore file creation by when something goes wrong with Mnesia which is a default case? Or is it possible to give limit on the size of file or constraint on count of files?

Since the MnesiaCore file gets created with different name each time, it will not overwrite the previous one. It causes flooding of MnesiaCore files in the working directory of my application, if the application has crashed for multiple times.

Comment: I had a quick look through the Mnesia source code, and couldn't find any configuration option for disabling or limiting core dump files.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18526512/3232487) one. Here, the erl_crash.dump file is redirected to /dev/null which I have tested and it works.